# In AngularJS is it possible to force a view to update from outside of it's controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs

EDIT:

The question as stated in the title is answered correctly below, so I think in the interest of people seeing how to do this, I should leave the question with the answer below.

It turns out that the framework I'm using has not fully abstracted away the variable-to-camelcase convention of Angular here.  It's abstracted away most everywhere else, just not here, and everything works now, so I don't need to force a redraw at all.  If anyone does, see the answer below. :)

Comment: If you have bi-directional binding, what are you trying to redraw? Can we get a more complete example, perhaps on Plunker? Also, *never* reference the DOM in your controller - that's bad juju.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller No, I can't reproduce the entire framework anywhere, unfortunately.  What I'm saying is that "=" is supposed to bind the data, but it's not.  I can change the variable I passed in as much as I want, the view never redraws itself.

Comment: I certainly don't want the "entire framework" but just a minimal example, as I have limited time. I don't know what you mean by "never redraws itself". If you mean that the value is not updated, then something is wrong in your code. But we can't tell you what without seeing some code.

Comment: THat's exactly what I'm trying to determine, @JoshDavidMiller, if there is something wrong with the ancilliary code that I'm using.  The  simple case works correctly, it doesnt work when it's in the framework we're using.  Really I'm just trying to figure out if I can force a view to refresh from outside of it's controller...?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Okay so this is a bad question. It turns out that the problem I was having is that I'm partially abstracted away from Angular by the framework that I'm using and I didn't know that the varible-interpolation-mechanism wasn't abstracted away from me in this case.  All I had to do was use-this-convention and I got the data correctly in camelCase inside of my directive.

Comment: @NathanCTresch Awesome. I'm glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the event binding inside your directive, not inside your controller. You must call `$apply()` from inside your directive if you make changes to some model and want those changes to be reflected outside the directive:

```
myApp.directive('someDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, elt, dirs) {
            elt.bind('click', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    // make changes to scope.model
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay so this is a bad question, I'm going to accept your answer mainly because it answers the question that I asked.  It turns out that the problem I was having is that I'm partially abstracted away from Angular by the framework that I'm using and I didn't know that the varible-interpolation-mechanism wasn't abstracted away from me in this case.  All I had to do was use-this-convention and I got the data correctly in camelCase inside of my directive.